# email a user if usage is above % PowerShell

Tags: powershell, server

I'm fairly new to PowerShell coding and I would like to notify users if they

1. Have files bigger than 100GB
2. Their current usage of the server is above 50%

A little background:
We have a server on where we run SAS, with a total of 25 users.
Our server is limited and currently we manually monitor the server for usage.
My goal is to notify users by either email or a popup that they have exceeded 1) or 2).

The following code returns a file with the folders, the folder name and the size. I also need to return the username which can be found in "properties">"Security">"User names".
How do I return the user name?

I will call this PowerShell with a batch file every 30 minutes and output the log, and then run another batch file with SAS code that emails the appropriate user. Is there a way I could do that with powershell?

```
$startFolder = "I:\SAS"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

[SS of the Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5RgC.png)

Comment: I don't have experience sending automated emails through PowerShell, but it *is* fairly common and there are plenty of examples on Google etc.  You could migrate all of your functionality into PowerShell to make it more easily managed.

What are you referring to when you say "usage of the server is above 50%" do you mean processing, disk usage, etc?

Comment: Yes CPU/Memory usage.

Comment: Do they have a single process, are the processes run from their user context?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the answer. Everyone has their own unique login and interface on the server. I have attached a SS of the task manager

Comment: I found a script that also returns the username.

Comment: How are you determining which user to email?  Are you using the directory where the file was found e.g. in a user's home folder, the owner property of the file, or are you determinining it from the access control list on the file

Comment: Using the code below I can link the username to their email address from a directory. The username I can determine from the access control list

Answer (score 1):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Get folder sizes in specified tree.  
.DESCRIPTION
    Script creates an HTML report with owner information, when created, 
    when last updated and folder size.  By default script will only do 1
    level of folders.  Use Recurse to do all sub-folders.

    Update the PARAM section to match your environment.
.PARAMETER Paths
    Specify the path(s) you wish to report on.  Specify an array of paths for
    mulitple folders to be processed, or pipe folders in.
.PARAMETER ReportPath
    Specify where you want the HTML report to be saved
.PARAMETER Sort
    Specify which column you want the script to sort by.  

    Valid colums are:
        Folder                  Sort by folder name
        Size                    Sort by folder size, largest to smallest
        Created                 Sort by the Created On column
        Changed                 Sort by the Last Updated column
        Owner                   Sort by Owner
.PARAMETER Descending
    Switch to control how you want things sorted.  By default the script
    will sort in an ascending order.  Use this switch to reverse that.
.PARAMETER Recurse
    Report on all sub-folders
.EXAMPLE
    .\Get-FolderSizes

    Run script and use defaults
.EXAMPLE
    .\Get-FolderSizes -Path "c:\Windows" -ReportPath "c:\Scripts"

    Run the script and report on all folers in C:\Windows.  Save the
    HTML report in C:\Scripts
.EXAMPLE
    .\Get-FolderSizes -Path "c:\Windows" -ReportPath "c:\Scripts" -Recurse

    Run the script and report on all folers in C:\Windows.  Save the
    HTML report in C:\Scripts.  Report on all sub-folders.
.OUTPUTS
    FolderSizes.HTML in specified Report Path
.NOTES
    Author:         Martin Pugh
    Twitter:        @thesurlyadm1n
    Spiceworks:     Martin9700
    Blog:           www.thesurlyadmin.com

    Changelog:
        1.6         Added some error trapping to test if the path provided is valid.
        1.5         Added ability to process multiple paths, both from array input as well as
                    from the pipeline.  Added verbose logging.  Also switched away from using
                    the COM Object.  While the COM object is much faster, it will return 0 if
                    it has any problem in the folder structure (such as a typical access denied
                    when running against C:\Windows).  I figure SOME result is better than none.
                    Tightened up the final report so it looks a little better.
        1.41        @SPadminWV found a bug in the Total Size reporting.
        1.4         Add Sort and descending parameter
        1.3         Added Recurse parameter, default behavior is to now do 1 level of folders,
                    recurse will do all sub-folders.
        1.2         Added function to make the rows in the table alternating colors
        1.1         Updated to use COM Object Scripting.FileSystemObject which
                    should increase performance.  Inspired by MS Scripting Guy
                    Ed Wilson.
        1.0         Initial Release
.LINK
    http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1738-get-foldersizes
.LINK
    http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/286820-how-to-export-list-all-folders-from-drive-the-list-should-include
.LINK
    http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/05/weekend-scripter-sorting-folders-by-size.aspx
#>  
#requires -Version 3.0
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]]$Paths = "I:\SASWork",
    [string]$ReportPath = "I:\SASWork",
    [ValidateSet("Folder","Folders","Size","Created","Changed","Owner")]
    [string]$Sort = "Folder",
    [switch]$Descending,
    [switch]$Recurse
)

Begin {
    Function AddObject {
        Param ( 
            $FileObject
        )
        $RawSize = (Get-ChildItem $FileObject.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum

        If ($RawSize)
        {   $Size = CalculateSize $RawSize
        }
        Else
        {   $Size = "0.00 MB"
        }
        $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Folder Name' = $FileObject.FullName
            'Created on' = $FileObject.CreationTime
            'Last Updated' = $FileObject.LastWriteTime
            Size = $Size
            Owner = (Get-Acl $FileObject.FullName).Owner
            RawSize = $RawSize
        }
        Return $Object
    }

    Function CalculateSize {
        Param (
            [double]$Size
        )
        If ($Size -gt 1000000000)
        {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} GB" -f ($Size / 1GB)
        }
        Else
        {   $ReturnSize = "{0:N2} MB" -f ($Size / 1MB)
        }
        Return $ReturnSize
    }

    Function Set-AlternatingRows {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
            [object[]]$Lines,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$CSSEvenClass,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$CSSOddClass
        )
        Begin {
            $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
        }
        Process {
            ForEach ($Line in $Lines)
            {   $Line = $Line.Replace("<tr>","<tr class=""$ClassName"">")
                If ($ClassName -eq $CSSEvenClass)
                {   $ClassName = $CSSOddClass
                }
                Else
                {   $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
                }
                Return $Line
            }
        }
    }

    #Validate sort parameter
    Switch -regex ($Sort)
    {   "^folder.?$" { $SortBy = "Folder Name";Break }
        "created" { $SortBy = "Created On";Break }
        "changed" { $SortBy = "Last Updated";Break }
        default { $SortBy = $Sort }
    }

    $Report = @()
    $TotalSize = 0
    $NumDirs = 0
    $Title = @()
    Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Script begins!"
}

Process {
    ForEach ($Path in $Paths)
    {   #Test if path exists
        If (-not (Test-Path $Path))
        {   $Result += $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                'Folder Name' = $Path
                'Created on' = ""
                'Last Updated' = ""
                Size = ""
                Owner = "Path not found"
                RawSize = 0
            }
            $Title += $Path
            Continue
        }

        #First get the properties of the starting path
        $NumDirs ++
        Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Now working on $Path..."
        $Root = Get-Item -Path $Path 
        $Result = AddObject $Root
        $TotalSize += $Result.RawSize
        $Report += $Result
        $Title += $Path

        #Now loop through all the subfolders
        $ParamSplat = @{
            Path = $Path
            Recurse = $Recurse
        }
        ForEach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem @ParamSplat | Where { $_.PSisContainer }))
        {   $Report += AddObject $Folder
            $NumDirs ++
        }
    }
}

End {
    #Create the HTML for our report
    $Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
.odd  { background-color:#ffffff; }
.even { background-color:#dddddd; }
</style>
<Title>
Folder Sizes for "$Path"
</Title>
"@

    $TotalSize = CalculateSize $TotalSize

    $Pre = "<h1>Folder Sizes Report</h1><h3>Folders processed: ""$($Title -join ", ")""</h3>"
    $Post = "<h2><p>Total Folders Processed: $NumDirs<br>Total Space Used:  $TotalSize</p></h2>Run on $(Get-Date -f 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')</body></html>"

    #Create the report and save it to a file
    $HTML = $Report | Select 'Folder Name',Owner,'Created On','Last Updated',Size | Sort $SortBy -Descending:$Descending | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post -Head $Header | Set-AlternatingRows -CSSEvenClass even -CSSOddClass odd | Out-File $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html

    #Display the report in your default browser
    & $ReportPath\FolderSizes.html

    Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): $NumDirs folders processed"
    Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Script completed!"
}
```